# How to automatically reload a MongoDB document in pymongo or mongoengine when accessing its attributes?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I am using MongoDB for application setting and in my Python code, I read the setting document from db using mongoengine that is a high-level wrapper for pymongo.
I'm able to reload the document each time accessing its attributes like this (assuming that there is a document in Setting collection in MongoDB):

```
import time
import mongoengine

class Setting(mongoengine.Document):
    log_level = mongoengine.StringField(default='info')

setting = Setting.objects[0]
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    setting.reload()
    print(setting.log_level)
```

But, I'm interested in a method to make Setting document automatically reloaded each time accessing log_level attribute. Is there a clean way to do this in mongoengine? I prefer to have a code like this and my Setting be always sync with db:

```
...
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print(setting.log_level)
```

I've read mongoengine doc a bit more to find a nice way and I've found no_cache() method that can be used to force the Setting class to returned a non-caching queryset. With this, I'm a bit closer:

```
def get_setting():
    return Setting.objects.no_cache()[0] 

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print(get_setting().log_level)
```

Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can write a custom method which does that.
Pseudocode:

```
def get_reloaded_attr(obj,attr):
    obj.reload()
    return getattr(obj,attr)
```

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. But I'm trying to find a cleaner way because I have to use this setting document everywhere in my code and calling a function such as get_reloaded_attr(setting, 'log_level') is verbose and indirect.